# ListView column shading bug

Tags: c++, listview, c++builder, c++builder-xe5

I want to add a color fill for selected column.

Drawing items I do in `ListView1CustomDrawItem` handler:

```
Sender->Canvas->Brush->Color = RGB(200, 200, 255);

   if(Item->Selected)
   {
   Sender->Canvas->Brush->Color = (Sender->Focused() ? clBlue : clRed);
   }

Sender->Canvas->Lock();
Sender->Canvas->FillRect(Item->DisplayRect(drBounds));
Sender->Canvas->TextOut(Item->DisplayRect(drLabel).Left, Item->DisplayRect(drLabel).Top + 1, Item->Caption);
Sender->Canvas->Unlock();
DefaultDraw = false;
```

And if I understand correctly, drawing the selected column I should do in the `ListView1CustomDraw` handler:

```
TRect rect;
rect = ARect;
rect.Right = Sender->Column[0]->Width;

Sender->Canvas->Brush->Color = RGB(245, 245, 245);


Sender->Canvas->Lock();
Sender->Canvas->FillRect(rect);
Sender->Canvas->Unlock();
```

And the result is:

http://i63.fastpic.ru/big/2014/1120/ba/e5b6d30eb9e05bbe3661aed295c28aba.jpg

It can also be seen on the video:
http://youtu.be/XGXpWCUtGbU

As you can see, when I move (do not click) the cursor over the items, they are redrawn incorrectly. But the items must be drawn over the column colored rectangle.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the `OnCustomDrawSubItem` event as well. The `OnCustomDrawItem` event only applies to the first column.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, do you have the source code for drawing shaded column  in ListView?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for. And you already know how to draw items, you just need to handle both `OnCustomDrawItem` and `OnCustomDrawSubItem` events. Are you doing that yet?

Comment: The code that I wrote in the <code>OnCustomDrawSubItem<code>, does not work. This event is never invoked. And tell me what I should write in the <code>OnCustomDrawSubItem<code> handler? Maybe you have a working example?